# Mapbox GL JS - possible to get the street name for a specific lng/lat?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, osm.pbf

I have a `Mapbox GL JS` implementation that gets its data from a vector `mbtiles` file that I downloaded from [www.openmaptiles.com](http://openmaptiles.com). I use `tileserver.php` with the `mbtiles` file to serve the `PBF` data, which Mapbox GL can use to display the map.

Is there any way to extract data from this in a specific area or lng/lat-pair using Javascript ?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your setup? What do you mean "openstreetmap PBF's" - do you mean Mapbox Streets? Or are you somehow processing OSM data into vector tiles yourself?

Comment: I edited the question to make it a bit more clear.  It's vector data in some kind of PBF-format that is extracted from the .mbtiles file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added your sources to a Mapbox-GL-JS map and created a layer ("roads", say) that references it, you can use [`map.querySourceFeatures()`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#querysourcefeatures) to get features at a given screen location. To turn a lat/long into a screen location, you need to use `map.project()`.

So all up:

```
var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(map.project([mylng, mylat]), { layers: ['roads'] });
var p = features && features[0] && features[0].properties;
```

`p` now contains the properties of the object at that location.